# Plot-oriented adult movies

Tags: adult-movies

Despite struggling to word this question in a manner that won't be off-topic;
Do some movie studios create adult movies which are mainly plot-oriented? That is, movies with prevalent adult content, but which would also provide an interesting storyline?

Do studios specializing in such content exist? Is there a specific term to search by, something that would draw a distinct line between the general adult media industry?

Comment: Lars von Trier certainly seems to be trying.

Comment: I don't think I would ever watch an adult movie for the plot :P

Comment: The plot is simple, some ladies order a pizza for delivery...

Comment: You mean like the Pirates movies?

Answer (score 10):

There are several production companies that produce these type of films. And it appears to be a gender-driven demand. In general terms it is known as Porn-by-Women-for-Women, under the assumption that female producers and directors are best at delivering the type of erotic film that appeals to women. Some notable producers or directors are former female stars, namely Nina Hartley, Candida Royalle, and Skye Blue.

If you search the web, you will find guides such as [this](http://www.pornmoviesforwomen.com/femaleporndirectors.htm) that will clarify the rationale and lead to further information. In general terms, women are interested in stories devoted to story and plot, in addition to sex.

Here the description of Bright Desire, a representative production company:
*Bright Desire is about expanding the definition of porn, leaving behind the tired and sexist cliches of the mainstream and embracing positive depictions of sex. This is porn that features real connections, intimacy, laughter, emotion and passion. It features real life couples and a diversity of body types. It ignores the rules about what's "gay" and what's "straight". It's for women, for men, for everyone.*